# PHP explode function with file_get_contents?

Tags: php, explode

```
   <?php
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
print_r (explode(" ",$str));
?>
```

The above code prints an array as an output.

If I use

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/data.txt');
print_r (explode(" ",$homepage));
    ?>
```

However it does not display individual numbers in the text file in the form of an array.

Ultimately I want to read numbers from a text file and print their frequency. The data.txt has 100,000 numbers. One number per line.

Comment: Did you get any result? Are you sure that the numbers are not separated by an other whitespace character, like a tab?

Comment: When I used the "\n" I got the result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A new line is not a space. You have to explode at the appropriate new line character combination. E.g. for Linux:

```
explode("\n",$homepage)
```

Alternatively, you can use `preg_split` and the character group `\s` which matches every white space character:

```
preg_split('/\s+/', $homepage);
```

---

Another option (maybe faster) might be to use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Answer (score 5):

If you want the content of a file as an array of lines, there is already a built-in function

```
var_dump(file('http://www.example.com/data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
```

See [Manual: file()](http://php.net/file)

Answer (score 0):

Try exploding at "\n"

```
print_r (explode("\n",$homepage));
```

Also have a look at:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.file.php

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it by using a Regexp also:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/data.txt");
preg_match_all("/^[0-9]+$/", $homepage, $matches);
```

This will give you the variable $matches which contains an array with numbers. This will ensure it will only retrieve lines that have numbers in them in case the file is not well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You are not exploding the string using the correct character. You either need to explode on new line separator (`\n`) or use a regular expression (will be slower but more robust). In that case, use [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-split.php)